# How to add placeholders in customized module?

Tags: 7

I am new to drupal, currently I am creating a new module for forms. Inside of module I have added the code as follows .

```
$form['first name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First Name'),
    );
```

In this case I wanted to use place holders for text fields. So how can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by placeholders? a default value that prefills the textfield or some watermark text that disappears when you focus the textfield?
for a default value you can use the `#default_value` key in the text field definition.

for a watermark i recommend the [Placeholder](https://www.drupal.org/project/placeholder) module. the module enables you to use a `#placeholder` key in your field definition.

cheers
j